# How to use in-app billing to disable ads from application?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I want to use in-app billing to control some application features,

actually i want to remove ads from users who decide to support my app.

The problem is not how to use in-app billing for purchase, but how to manage the case on which the user will uninstall the app;ication and reinstall it later.

In that case how the application should know if the upgrade has been purchased or not?

I must implement an external service? Or there is also a support for tracking orders by a specific user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an external service. You can set your InApp purchase item to ['managed purchase'](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-purchase-type) on Google Play (Android Market). On app startup, send [RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html#billing-request) BillingRequest to Google Play. This request retrieves a user's transaction status for managed purchases. You should send this request only when you need to retrieve a user's transaction status, which is usually only when your application is reinstalled or installed for the first time on a device.